# pygame - pixel collision map

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game with pygame and I need a map where the user can select a country by clicking on it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Top tip: try doing it, and come back if there's something specific you want to solve. This sounds a bit like you want someone to do it for you.

Comment: I would suggest you start with this book: http://inventwithpython.com/chapters/

Comment: Is your map a bitmap image? Are the countries different colors?

Comment: its a png image,i could make diferent colors

Comment: i alread tried, that why im asking for help

i created an image of each country and then tried pixel perfect collision but or all the countries are select or none.

the other ideia would be creating an 'invisible' image so when there is a click i check the color that was clicked and know the country, but i dont know how to get the color from a click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you find that done, I see no easy way of doing that --
You have to start by having a World map, of course -- this one in Wikipedia seems a nice starting point:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/BlankMap-World6.svg

--Ah, I see by your comments you have the map drawn --
Yes.if all you need is to get the color for a click, that is easier -
Pick the click coordinates with the mouse event for the click:

```
e = pygame.event.poll()
if e == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    pos = e.pos
    # where "screen" is your variable holding the screen surface color = screen.get_at((pos))
```

Comment: A bit old but i thought i would throw my idea in, you could have a second image set up (not drawn) the same size as the other one that you use to do the lookup on, this would mean you dont need the countrys to have solid colours

Answer (score 0):

If every country has another color and you know it, you could detect it with:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([100,100])
print(screen.get_at([50,50]))#returns tuple with color values
pygame.quit()
```

I hope this helps to solve your problem